# Stack push issue Double and Character

Tags: java, stack

I've been stuck on this Stack problem for a couple days now. I get one thing working another thing breaks, but I'm almost done! The issue that I'm running into now is that I get a calculation to work but when I try and pop the next item, which is now a double, I get an error...

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at NodeStack.postFix(NodeStack.java:207)`

I did a little bit of research and debugging and it seems that when I'm popping the current item which is now a double and not a character I get the null pointer...which makes sense. The issue that I'm having is how to handle it. This is just a snippet of what is going on. I'm not sure what I can do.

```
        if(ch=='+'){
            E one=(E) myStack.pop();
            E two=(E) myStack.pop();

            String first=numbers.get(one);
            String second=numbers.get(two);

            double temp=Double.parseDouble(first)+Double.parseDouble(second);

            myStack.push(temp);
        }
```

Should I be adding an if/else statement somewhere in there to deal with whether or not it's a character or digit, if that is the case how would I go about doing that? I hope that I was detailed enough about this particular issue.

Comment: Did you check the values of `first` and `second`?

Comment: I got it working. Now there are a few logic errors with ^

Answer (score 0):

Probably the String variables first or second are null.

Here is the documentation for Double.parseDouble : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

```
 public static double parseDouble(String s)
                      throws NumberFormatException

 Throws:
 NullPointerException - if the string is null
 NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.
```